# NoClassDefFoundError on payara

Tags: java, glassfish, payara

Quite recently I migrated my development from Glassfish 4.1 to Payara-4.1.1.161.1.

Today I reopened project not touched for a few months.
When I try to compile and run the project I see the following in the console log

```
        Severe:   WebModule[/EstoreAdmin]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions/ClassNotFoundExceptionMapper
    at com.app.service.ApplicationConfig.addRestResourceClasses(ApplicationConfig.java:27)
    at com.app.service.ApplicationConfig.getClasses(ApplicationConfig.java:16)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig$3.run(ResourceConfig.java:1234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.registerComponentsOf(ResourceConfig.java:1216)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1190)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1174)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5732)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5977)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.ClassNotFoundExceptionMapper
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1795)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    ... 70 more
```

I spent a lot of time trying to find out what is going on, reverted the project to the very first stage and still I couldn't start it.

In the desperate move I decided that I would try to publish this project on the old Glassfish 4.1 (it is still on my hdd).
And it started without any problems.

I have no idea what is the source of the problem. 
It is somehow related to ide generated part

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
  }

  /**
   * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
   * It is automatically populated with
   * all resources defined in the project.
   * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
   */
  private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.ClassNotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.ConversionExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.DatabaseExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.EntityExistsExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IOExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IllegalAccessExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.IllegalStateExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.InvocationTargetExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.JAXBExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.JPARSConfigurationExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.JPARSExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.MalformedURLExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NamingExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NoResultExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NoSuchMethodExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.NonUniqueResultExceptionExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.OptimisticLockExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.PersistenceExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.PessimisticLockExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.QueryTimeoutExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.RollbackExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.TransactionRequiredExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.exceptions.UnsupportedMediaTypeExceptionMapper.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.EntityResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.PersistenceResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.PersistenceUnitResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.QueryResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.SingleResultQueryResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.EntityResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.PersistenceResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.PersistenceUnitResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.QueryResource.class);
        resources.add(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.resources.unversioned.SingleResultQueryResource.class);
  }
```

I tried switching JDKs. Both JDK 1.8.77 and 1.8.91 behave the same way.
I also tried pre relase payara build, the same.

Could you give me some advice what to do in order to make this work with Payara, how to trace the error.

### edit 1

I believe that this behavior is somehow connected with the fact that my application uses 2 connections defined in persistence modules.

if I disabled line

```
addRestResourceClasses(resources);
```

then application started (but my login controller didn't work and application got exception on login attempt).

So I enabled that line again but in the login controller I replaced @ManagedBean with @Named and adjusted controller slightly.
After this I can't see errors anymore. I am not sure why this helped though.

### edit 2

@Mike disclosed the root of the problem. It was caused by too old version of EclipseLink. I was using 2.5.2 and the correct one was 2.6.x

Comment: There seems to be a jar(s) you are missing in the classpath when you are trying to run the project in Payara. I would compare the working classpath in your Glassfish project to what you are running in the Payara project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions/ClassNotFoundExceptionMapper
```

The reason for this is that the ClassNotFoundExceptionMapper class has been refactored away in the version of Eclipselink that Payara uses.

GlassFish `4.1` uses < `2.5.2` (Payara `4.1.144` - which was derived from that version of GlassFish - integrated `2.5.2-RC1`) [which still contains that class](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/tree/2.5/dbws/org.eclipse.persistence.dbws/src/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions)

[The class has been replaced by the AbstractExceptionMapper](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/dbws/org.eclipse.persistence.dbws/src/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/rs/exceptions/AbstractExceptionMapper.java), so you will need to refactor your application to adapt.

The latest version of Payara which uses an Eclipselink version < `2.6` is version `4.1.151` which is over a year old now, so the recommended option is to change your code rather than downgrade the server.

Comment: Thank you. This explains the problem. I must have updated eclipselink to ver 2.6.2 yesterday and then my project run on Payara. Just downgraded to 2.5.2 in order to confirm that it would not run on Payara and it didn't so your answer is 100% correct.